# parse syntax error with inline reference to class function

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

I just want to know why PHP throws parse syntax error near '[' when I call a function like this.

```
switch ($this->remove_headers($page)['error'])
{
.
.
.
}
```

*$page* returned a jSon reply but some other function require the full header while this one need the return jSon only. Thus the *remove_headers* function

I tested on my local machine, it works fine. But it throws the parse syntax error when i upload it to my server.

i have to call it like this.

```
$msg = $this->remove_headers($page);
switch ($msg['error'])
{
.
.
.
}
```

I cannot check the PHP version on the server since im using a shared hosting and they disabled the phpinfo() function :(
my local machine running PHP version 5.4.19 (xampp)

Comment: Your server is running a version of PHP that does not support [function array de-referencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) (anything < 5.4). Also, who the hell disables `phpinfo()`, that's just dumb? You can get the version via [`phpversion()`](http://php.net/manual/function.phpversion.php) or the [`PHP_VERSION`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-version) constant

Comment: @Phil believe it or not, the hosting owner did disable it. `Warning: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons in`.. ok, just used phpversion(), and seems like the server is running 5.2.17.

Comment: @Phil - Thanks for giving the array de-referencing info. how do i mark it as the answer?

Comment: Time to get a new host. PHP 5.2 reached the end of its support life cycle in Jan 2011. Don't worry about marking an answer, there's not really a point. Just vote to close instead.

Comment: i dont see any vote to close here, so i'll just leave this as is. Thanks again for the info.